# New line sign in list Python

Tags: python, list, newline

I'm trying to do an array of arrays in python but without success, so I thought it would be a lot easier for me to work with a list with lines breaks.

What I'm doing is this :

```
board = []
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        board.append("0 ")
    board.append("\n")
print board
```

But when printing this , it comes out

```
['0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '\n', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '\n', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '\n', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '\n', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '\n', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '\n', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '\n', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '\n', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '\n', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '0 ', '\n']
```

I dont want the `'\n'` to show as `'\n'` , I want it to do a new line in the list.

How can I do it ?

Thank you in advance, Iliya :)

Comment: This will never work well. I think you should open a question about your problems with lists of lists.

Comment: Hello. See my answer, please. BTW, my advice is : don't be too hurry to upvote and accept answers, rapid answers by people eager to obtain points are not necessary the best ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an array of arrays (or in this case a list of lists) filled with 0's then you could use:

```
board = [[0]*10 for i in range(10)] # Generate 10 lists filled with 10 0's each.

for x in board:
    print x # Print out each [0,0,...0,0] on a new line.
```

Answer (score 3):

As usual, Ignacio didn't try to be more than laconic.

The reason why you obtain such a display as the one you show is that when a `print` statement is done to print an object `obj`, the method `obj.__str__` is called to obtain a string that can be written on the display.
Then, in your case, it is `board.__str__()` which is called.

The fact is that the element `'\n'` is a character but all the elements `'\n'` in `board` are not elements of a string : they are elements of a list and `__str__` is such that the elements of a list are represented inside a list as strings obtained from  `__repr__`  (see the doc on this method and its difference with `__str__`)
Understanding more precisely the process executed by the `print` statement would require to examine the code of the statement `print`, but I think it isn't in Python code but in C code (I suppose, I'm not very competent on this point)

That said, I think that what you want to obtain is a display like that:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

There's no need to place some `'\n'` characters in a list to obtain this display. Rather, do this:

```
board = []
for i in range(100):
    board.append('0 ')
# or better: board = ['0 ' for i in range(100)]
print '\n'.join(''.join(board[i:i+10]) for i in xrange(0,100,10))

print

board[6] = '4 '
board[18] = 'A '
board[30] = '9 '
board[77] = 'X '
print '\n'.join(''.join(board[i:i+10]) for i in xrange(0,100,10))
```

result

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 A 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

.

NB
In Python an `array` object is [an object of this type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#module-array)
The elements of an array have all the same constrained type which can't be the `array`'s type. So an object being an array of array means nothing in Python.

NB2
Now with the above definition of `board`, you have the problem that elements can be only strings of length 2 with a blank at the second character.
There are solutions to manage situations with elements being not strings, and of variable length, but it becomes rapidly complicated.
That's why the **Numpy** library has been created, to allow the easy manipulation of array presentation thanks to a type called `ndarray`

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not by printing the *representation* of the list...

```
print ''.join(board)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved my problem!

I will accept your answer in 10 minutes, it doesn't let me now :<

Answer (score 1):

You are printing a List. It will look as it is. "\n" will work if you print it as a string.
Please try

```
print "".join(board)
```

Answer (score 1):

If u want to see a new line use list of lists don't append '\n'

Here is the sample:

```
board = []
for i in range(10):
    temp = []
    for j in range(10):
        temp.append("0 ")
    board.append(temp)

for i in board:
    print ''.join(i)
```